# Can i break out of a while loop while in a catch block?

Tags: loops, while-loop, return, try-catch, break

So i got some code snippet that looks like this. The question is now, can i exchange the return right here with a break to get out of the while loop?
I'm asking cause according to our guidelines there shouldn't be multiple returns in one function.
The question is about c++.

```
while (true)
{
    if (state)
    {
        try{...}
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    if (...)
    {...}
}
```

My function is much more complex than in the example i've given and i don't want to recreate the scenario.
I'm just hoping for a quick answer and that my explanation was understandable.